# Converting a numeric string to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to do the following. I have a string that contains only numbers. I want it to convert into an integer array that contains its digits.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class proba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ymd = "12345678";

        int length = ymd.length();

        int[] numbersArray = new int[length];

        for (int count = 0; count > length; count++) {
            numbersArray[count] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ymd.charAt(count)));
        }

        System.out.println("YMD: " + ymd);
        System.out.println("Array: " + Arrays.toString(numbersArray));

    }

}
```

However, the result I get is:
YMD: 12345678
Array: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `count < length`, not `count > length`.

Comment: Oh, yes! It was a very funny mistake. Thanks.

Comment: pls consider acceptig the anwer if it helped you solve the problem.